# Adding legend to heatmap

Tags: r, colors, legend, heatmap

I'm trying to build a heatmap using the heatmap() funtion. I was able to obtain the graph with its dendogram and to set the color using the RColorBrewer Palette. What I would like to do now is add a legend color bar on the side of the heatmap  that show the range of colors used from the lowest to the highest value. Can anyone help me in doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show legend in heatmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395558/how-to-show-legend-in-heatmap) Also note that if you are trying to add a continuous legend, that is not easily done with base R `stats::heatmap`. You might look into the `pheatmap` package.